# How can i get current product inside a hook?

Tags: prestashop

How can i get the current product inside hookdisplayTop ?

This is the current way i'm making sure i'm in the "product" page :

```
if ( Dispatcher::getInstance()->getController() == "product") {
  //i'm in the product page
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You want to detect if you are at product page, or you want to get current product id? Please clearify and then i will write down you how you can do that.

Comment: i want to get the current product object if i'm in the product page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're in the ProductController then you can always get the product_id of the current product without resorting to an override (these can quickly get out of hand if overused and should be a last resort):

```
if ($id_product = (int)Tools::getValue('id_product'))
    $product = new Product($id_product, 
                           true,
                           $this->context->language->id, 
                           $this->context->shop->id);
if (!Validate:: isLoadedObject($product))
    return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

```
class ProductController extends ProductControllerCore
{
  public function getProduct() 
  {
    return $this->product;
  }
}
```

1. Created an override of "ProductController" (code above)
2. In the hook just call : $this->context->controller->getProduct()